# Bash script to Unrar and UnZip archives into directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an old script where I extract the contents of archives into a new directory with the name of the archives. I need to simplify this as I find it inefficient since the commands run regardless. I'm not an expert with bash, and this worked for a while, but has become unbearable of late.

I get constant errors because the directory is already created or is not a unzip/unrar archive.
I don't know how to check if the file is unrar or zip format prior to starting the script so I don't know how to put together a proper if/else for loop. I'm no expert with bash and this is just a small portion of a much larger script all written in bash years ago.

```
for x in $(find -name '*.cbr'); do dir=${x%%.cbr}; mkdir "$dir"; unzip -d "$dir" $x; done

for x in $(find -name '*.cbr'); do dir=${x%%.cbr}; mkdir "$dir"; unrar e $x "$dir"; done
 
for x in $(find -name '*.cbz'); do dir=${x%%.cbz}; mkdir "$dir"; unzip -d "$dir" $x; done

for x in $(find -name '*.cbz'); do dir=${x%%.cbz}; mkdir "$dir"; unrar e $x "$dir"; done
```

Comment: So... what do you want the behavior to be if the directory already exists?

Comment: @root I'm hoping to simplify this somehow, create the directories, then extract the archives to the directories. I'm just not sure, how to bring this into a for loop properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback, I ended up doing something else.

```
 for x in $(find -name '*.cbr' -o -name '*.cbz');
 do dir=${x%.*};
     mkdir "$dir";
     unrar e $x "$dir" || unzip -d "$dir" $x;
 done
```

Which is what I was looking to do, only attempt to create the directory once, and make a choice between unrar or unzip. Also, far more clean than what i previously had.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the file types manually with `file` or some smarter alternative, but my recommendation would be to just change your tool. `atool` works with just about any archive format and unarchives into a directory formatted the way you're creating directories, by default (and creates a directory `Unpack-[random number]` if there's already a file or directory by that name). Then you could just use one loop, remove the need to create a destination directory.

```
valid_exts=("zip", "rar") # etc
for f in $(find . -type f); do
  if [[ "${valid_exts[*]}" == *"${f: -3}"* ]]; then
    aunpack "$f"
  fi
done
```

`atool` is available in most package repositories.

If that won't work for you, I think it would be easier to use Python or some other language to do the tedious work: write out a dictionary of filetypes and unarchiving commands, then use a similar loop and call the commands from your higher-level script.

Comment: I'm looking into this one. I wanted to use the tools I already have, but it looks like I would need more skill with an if/else statement for utilizing unrar/unzip commands in the for loop.